# Handling the soapClientexception in C#

Tags: c#

can someone help here please.. This is my code.

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{
    EBServiceReference.EBServiceSoapClient Ebservice = new EBServiceReference.EBServiceSoapClient();

    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        colour.colordesign(this);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Ebservice.GetBranch();
        Common.PopulateCombo(cbBranchId, ds, "BranchName", "BranchID");
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //ClearAll();
            errorProviderLogin.Clear();
            if (ValidateControls() == 1)
            {
                int branchid = Convert.ToInt32(cbBranchId.SelectedValue);
                string username = txtUserName.Text;
                string password = txtPassword.Text;
                int ret = Ebservice.Login(branchid, username, password);

                if (ret == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Common.LoginMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataSet ds_user = null;
                    ds_user = Ebservice.GetUser(ret);
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds_user.Tables[0].Rows[0][3]))
                    {//it is a temporary pwd
                        change_pwd chg = new change_pwd(ds_user);
                        chg.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    MDIEvolveBanking objMDIEvolveBanking = new MDIEvolveBanking();
                    this.Hide();
                    objMDIEvolveBanking.logedinuser = txtUserName.Text;
                    objMDIEvolveBanking.Show();
                }
                Common.LoginID = ret;
                Common.BranchID = Convert.ToInt32(cbBranchId.SelectedValue);
                //}
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Common.WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "Error in btnLogin_Click");
        }

    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmLogin_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keys)e.KeyValue == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void txtUserName_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void gbLogin_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void frmLogin_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    #region [Validate Controls]
    public int ValidateControls()
    {
        int result=1;
        if ((Validation.StringOnly(txtUserName.Text)==0))
        {
            errorProviderLogin.SetError(txtUserName, "Enter Name");
            result = 0;
        }
        if (Validation.StringOnly(txtPassword.Text)==0)
        {
            errorProviderLogin.SetError(txtPassword, "Enter Password");
            result = 0;
        }
            return result;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

this is the error am receiving.

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'EBServiceReference.EBServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

Comment: Can we see your configuration file?

Comment: Can we see your configuration file? @Gerald